# Unable to start debugging on the Web Server. Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am running visual studio 2008 on vista business 64-bit. I am getting the following exception when I try to debug against IIS.

"Unable to start debugging on the web server. The object identifier does not represent a valid object".

IIS and Visual Studio are on the same box.

I've tried adding Windows Authentication but no luck (my app requires forms authentication, fyi).

Any thoughts? I have a binding on the Web Site. The IIS app is a Web SIte not a virtual directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the application run ok locally when you're not trying to debug?  Do any other web apps allow you to debug?

Comment: Terry, I am trying to debug on the same box. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it runs fine when not debugging.

Comment: How are you launching the debugger? Via the respective properties of your project or via attaching the debugger to the w3p.exe process?

Answer (score 3):

You have switch on Windows Authentication in IIS

Comment: This was my solution to this problem, I thought it was something Windows 7 specific. Looks like not the solution to the original poster though.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pc and the webserver on the same Windows domain?  If not, or there is a DMZ between your pc and the web server you could experience problems unless you've explicitly setup trust between the machines.

Comment: They are on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS right click on your project go to Asp.Net tab change the version to your current verion you are using.

This problem comes when you are using a higher version and decided to switch to a lower version and vice versa changing to your version might solve the problem