# Unable to start debugging on the Web Server. Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis

I am running visual studio 2008 SP1 on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise` `64-bit`. I am getting the following exception when I try to debug against IIS.

"Unable to start debugging on the web server. The object identifier does not represent a valid object".

IIS and Visual Studio are on the same box.

**I've tried enabling Windows Authentication but no luck** (my app requires *forms authentication*, fyi).

Any thoughts? I have a binding on the Web Site. The IIS app is a Web SIte not a virtual directly.

Thanks!

**P.S**
I have posting this as a new questions since the previous question I found is not answered and the solution provided in that question is not working as well.
Previous Question:
[Unable to start debugging on the Web Server. Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841376/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 2):

When I hit this problem I opened the basic settings in IIS and checked the app pool set for the web site. It was set to "Default" and not (as it should have been in this case) to ".NET 2". Changing that setting was the fix.

Comment: Good job, Mike.  This solved it for me, too.  Except, I didn't have to change the framework, I had to change the Managed Pipeline Mode to Classic, not Integrated.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. My default app pool was 4.0, switching to the classic app pool (2.0) solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue in VS2008 after I did a "get latest" out of TFS.  VS wanted me to create the virtual directory, although it already existed.  I said no the first time, but then the project wouldn't display in VS.  So I said "go ahead and make the directory."

After the directory was created I started getting the "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information" error message.

For me it ended up being that when the new virtual directory was created automatically through VS, it created incorrect IIS configurations.

There are multiple projects in my solution, and for each one I had to do the following steps:

1. right click the project.
2. select "properties".
3. select the "web" tab.
4. ensure that "Use local IIS Web server" was selected.
5. change the "Project Url" path to be what it should have been.

I also had to reconfigure the IIS settings because of the recreation of the virtual directory.  I did the following for each directory created:

1. open IIS.
2. right click on directory.
3. go to "Manage Application"
4. go to "Advanced Settings"
5. corrected the "Physical Path", as that had changed to something
   that was not correct.

After I did these it worked correctly.

There are also more suggestions I found on this site, but none worked for me.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/07/unable-to-start-debugging-on-web-server.html?showComment=1363115311254#c1277193809542815038

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestions on troubleshooting:

- Start with checking out the IIS log files. That may give you some idea why planets are not aligned.
  The following blog entry should be a decent starting point:
  http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2008/06/03/visual-studio-2008-unable-to-debug-asp-net-app-on-iis-7-0.aspx.
- Try failed request tracing (IIS 7 feature) as described on
  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/
  may be of some help too.